# IMO Notifications on Home Screen Won't Go Away

Tags: notifications

I have a **Samsung** Phone with **Android Pie** and with **IMO** messaging app installed.

Every now and then I see a big pop-up notification on lock screen with nothing else. I have to press on the home button then unlock my phone.

I disabled IMO notifications by going to **`Settings > Apps > IMO > Notifications`** and turning **`off`** the **`Show Notifications`** setting.

That did not work, so I disabled the whole lock screen notifications from **`Settings > Lock Screen > Notifications`** and I turned it **`off`**.

It did not work either.

**What should I do? What am I missing?**